# How can humans on the machine-infested Earth breathe without oxygen masks outside of Zion?

Tags: the-matrix

After the machines took over, it seems that there is no significant organic life left on the surface of the planet. No sunshine ever reaches the surface, so there is no significant plant life to produce oxygen. The machine cities are unlikely to maintain the delicate balance of the atmosphere, because oxygen is corrosive to them. So, how can it be that there is breathable air on the surface of the planet after so many centuries (millenia?) without photosynthesis?

Comment: What makes you say oxygen is corrosive to the machines?

Comment: @AidanO: Because that's the definition of corrosion.

Comment: We can produce Oxygen artificially even today. In case of Zion (with advanced tech), they could invest upto high extent for it because it was for their survival...

Comment: @Sachin Shekhar: this is why I wrote "outside of Zion". They might make Oxygen in Zion, but what about the rest of the world?

Comment: @vsz When did you see a human walking on surface? Those who were outside Zion were in their ships.

Comment: And, those who were captured by machines were facilitated by machines for oxygen.

Comment: @bitmask "Corrosion is the result of a chemical reaction between a metal and its surroundings during which the metal is oxidized." Who says the machines are made of metal?

Comment: @AidanO: I was referring to the "oxygen"

Comment: @SachinShekhar At the very least there is oxygen in the old subway tunnels (at least twice the humans are seen walking in them), as well as in the machine city (seen when Neo hooks in to the Matrix through the machines to fight Smith).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There would be residual oxygen from the time before sunlight was blocked out. Without sunlight and plants, most oxygen consuming life forms on Earth would have perished within weeks, if not days, which is not enough time to deplete a substantial percentage of the 20% oxygen atmosphere that we enjoy.

The machines would have taken care of the humans and their oxygen consuming industries. Natural oxidation would gradually take oxygen out of the atmosphere, but the Matrix is probably not old enough for this process to have made the air unbreathable.

You might ask what happens when oxygen is consumed by the humans plugged in to the Matrix. This plot hole is related to the plot hole about the viability of human bio-electricity. The only answer we have is that it is "combined with a form of fusion".

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but I'd like to know what you mean when you say there's a plot hole in "what happens when oxygen is consumed ... in the Matrix". Is this really a plot hole? The matrix is only a simulation that your mind is *very* connected to. You can't stay plugged in forever because you can't gain sustenance from it, someone would have to feed you in 'the real world'.

Comment: I didn't mean the virtual oxygen inside the Matrix. I was talking about the actual oxygen consumption by the humans inside the pods. They're submerged in a liquid medium which by necessity must contain oxygen.

Comment: @HNL That isn't really a plot hole either as the machines could manufacture oxygen for this purpose.

Comment: @Xantec Using a "form of fusion", of course :)

Answer (score 13):

Let's do some math, shall we?

According to Wolfram Alpha, a [human](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=human) consumes

- 210 to 240 mL of oxygen (O2) per kg per hour

and weights around

- 62 kg

which results in an oxygen consumption of

- [1/3 m^3/day](http://%28%28225%20mL%20/%20kg%20/%20hour%29%20%2a%20%2862%20kg%29%29%20in%20m%5E3/day) of oxygen (O2)

According to Wikipedia, 3/4 of the atmosphere are contained in an

- [11 km radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth)

which gives us a volume of

- [5.6 * 10^9 km^3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284/3%29%20%2a%20pi%20%2a%20%28%28radius%20of%20earth%20%2b%2011%20km%29%5E3%20-%20%28radius%20of%20earth%29%5E3%29) (air)

or

- [10^9 km^3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%284/3%29%20%2a%20pi%20%2a%20%28%28radius%20of%20earth%20%2b%2011%20km%29%5E3%20-%20%28radius%20of%20earth%29%5E3%29%29%20%2a%200.2) (O2)

which results in

- [9 quadrillion years](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.2%2a%28%284/3%29%20%2a%20pi%20%2a%20%28%28radius%20of%20earth%20%2b%2011%20km%29%5E3%20-%20%28radius%20of%20earth%29%5E3%29%29/%28%28%28225%20mL%20/%20kg%20/%20hour%29%20%2a%20%2862%20kg%29%29%20in%20m%5E3/day%29%20in%20years)

of breathing time for one human.

Since there seem to be no fauna (since there is no flora), this means that the handful of people living on earth can do pretty nicely.

You might argue that I didn't take into account the different pressure levels in the atmosphere when computing this (right at the start) but I only accounted for 3/4 of the oxygen that is available in theory. Also, thermodynamics tells us that the oxygen would be distributed across the planet equally, even if consumed only at one point (Zion).

Comment: I have no idea if you are right, although I presume you are, but +1 for the calculations anyway!

Comment: @SchroedingersCat: Frankly, that number is that large that I have my doubts as well, but I see no error. Anyway, think about how large the earth is compared to a single room and think about how long you can breathe in a single room before even noticing that the quality of the air deteriorates (which is typically not directly related to the O2 ratio at first), let alone asphyxiating.

Comment: @bitmask What if we take into account the oxygen consumed by the humans inside the pods (see my comment on the other answer)? Also, you might also need to factor in the oxidation of naturally occurring substances and leftovers from the human civilization (e.g. millions, if not billions of tons of iron will oxidize).

Comment: @bitmask What makes you think that oxygen is consumed only by humans??

Comment: @SachinShekhar: The premise was that there is no flora (i.e. no oxygen production), this implies that there is no fauna. I.e. no life. The only thing that is left, like HNL pointed out, is oxidation.

Comment: There are some significant problems with that calculation, first being the calculation for the volume of the atmosphere. the atmosphere does not have a volume equivalent to a 11km radius sphere, but more appropriately, a spherical shell with inner radius of the earth, outer radius of that plus 11km. The atmosphere is also only about 21% oxygen. With partial pressure of O2 below about .16 bar (16% oxygen at sea level), humans begin to lose consciousness due to hypoxia. Even if the assumptions of oxygen surviving the machine war, the calculation is wrong.

Comment: @Slothsberry: I took all of that into account (except the conciousness factor). Look at the links. However, my description was misleading, because I didn't state where the 11 km went. However, the 0.16 factor would not affect the order of magnitude significantly (nothing more that an order of magnitude can be derived in this fashion, anyway).

Comment: My mistake on the volume. the volume of a sphere r=11km is 5.6x10^something, so I just assumed that the simpler, but incorrect, sphere calculation was performed instead of the shell calculation. I still think the number is at least an order of magnitude high (there's no way all aerobic life on the planet except humans was wiped out, not to mention oxygen-negative reactions that aren't metabolic), but it's still going to be a silly-large amount of time that a person could breathe

Comment: @Slothsberry: That's the point. Divide by a million if you like; It's still a billion years.

Comment: @bitmask Beyond fauna and oxidation, there're fire, explosions, volcanos etc.. In war, very high amount of oxygen is exhausted. So, you need to take care of that...

Comment: Not to mention that regardless of how much oxygen remains in the atmosphere the amount of chemicals toxic to humans is likely to be very high as well, due to the war, decomposing bio-matter, (machine) industry, rotting infrastructure etc..

Comment: Hm... that means, unless Machine industry is consuming oxygen at an alarming rate, there is plenty of oxygen for many, many generations of rebels to breathe.

Comment: @vsz: I'm not sure you should accept this answer. As many have pointed out, it doesn't reflect a lot of important factors that consume oxygen, besides people. Also it is certainly not an in-universe explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the comic *The Miller's Tale* (archived link [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20040614034230/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/rl_cmp/paulcMiller1a.html)) indicates that there is significant plant life left on the Earth's surface. (It is part of [The Matrix Comics](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Matrix_Comics) released by the Wachowskis' company Burlyman Entertainment and was posted on the official website, so it is canon.)

Here are some panels from the comic showing plant life and fungi, and even small animals:

[image: frogs and fungi]
[image: plant fields]
[image: weeds and forests]
[image: grass]

One of the last panels gives possible explanations for the survival of this plant life -- that genetic modifications and/or mutations have helped these "sun-loving plants" survive:

[image: mutation]

Since there is significant plant life left on the Earth, there is enough oxygen for humans on the surface of the Earth.